# jquery: a function after some time interval only if specific condition does not occur

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function!

When the user clicks on a div, that function is executed! I dont want that function to execute again if the user clicks on the div within 5 seconds.

What could be the solution for this?

Help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Throttling. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: A flag with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Is it a bad question? Why did it recieve so many negative votes!

Comment: @user1974333, lets say it that way, your question in your comment was better  than the one in the "question"... :)

Comment: Oh will try to make it better from next time!

Answer (score 1):

A simple timer would restrict that 5 sec click. See below,

```
var isClickAllowed = true;
$(element).click (function () {
    if (!isClickAllowed) return false;

    setTimeout(function () {
      isClickAllowed = true;
    }, 5000);
    isClickAllowed = false;
});
```